# Option to connect a React Native application to an Electron app in an offline situation

Tags: javascript, react-native, electron, offline, bonjour

I am trying to architect a solution in which a React Native mobile companion app could connect to an Electron app running a local database. A valid scenario would be scanning barcodes on the mobile app with no internet connection and then somehow relaying that information back to my electron app, which is running a local, offline database.

I am experimenting with the idea of running a local express server with mongodb and using bonjour to broadcast the http service, which could be picked up on the phone in the same way, but from my research mongodb+express in electron seems difficult. Any ideas on how to send data between the react native application and the electron app would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whilst I don't have experience with mongodb, [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) work great together. Your mobile React app would connect over your local wireless LAN to the server using socket.io's WebSocket (or HTTP long polling if unable to connect via WebSocket). I am currently experimenting with a local LAN HTML5 game and socket.io implementation and use is as easy as Node events and Electron IPC (event) calls.